# React - When refreshing getting always to initial page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm working on a project using react with flux architecture.

I have several views and a store called ContextStore in which I save the current view in the state, so that when an action to change the view is triggered this store change his state and the Main view listen and change it.

But the problem is that always when I refresh the page with F5 it always goes to the initial Views.

What is more, if I press the back button the View has no change.

I think that my problem is because when I refresh the Main view loads again the initial state. How could I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a router?

Comment: No, just a store which keeps the current view. In the Main view I have a switch to render the view

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into using a router to manage your views. Here's the one I use: https://github.com/rackt/react-router. When you transition to different views (routes) it adds to the history stack so you can use the back button. However, I don't have the use case where you need to stay on the current view when you refresh, so you might need to use cookies or session storage in those instances in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, when hitting F5 you are completely reseting all javascript, ergo the store looses its state. You need to use some kind of storage for saving the state. Classical ways are cookies, or you could use IndexedDB which is included into HTML5